# Moving oil out of a conical shaped tank

Tags: calculus, physics

I need some help finishing out a Calculus problem. I'm not sure how $d$ works (single value, or integral) at the end.

> A conical shaped tank, with its apex pointing upward is one fourth full of motor oil. That is, the initial depth of the oil in the center of the tank is 2.5 feet. The radius of the circular base of the tank if 4 feet. The height of the tank is 10 feet. Given that motor oils weighs $32\frac{lbs}{cubic foot}$, find the work required to pump the oil of of the top of the tank.

So, I know that

$$ v = \int_{0}^{2.5}{\pi\left(\frac{-2y + 20}{5}\right)^2}{dy} $$

And thus mass

$$ m = \int_{0}^{2.5}{\pi\left(\frac{-2y + 20}{5}\right)^2}{dy} \times \frac{32lbs}{ft^3} $$

And work is

$$ W = mgd $$

$$ W = \int_{0}^{2.5}{\pi\left(\frac{-2y + 20}{5}\right)^2}{dy} \times \frac{32lbs}{ft^3} \times 32.174 \frac{ft}{s^2} \times d $$

I'm stuck at what $d$ is. Is it 10? 7.5? A new integral? Or does it get put into the first integral?

Thanks!

Comment: If the tank is conical with height $10~\text{ft}$ and with a base of radius $4~\text{ft}$, then by similar triangles $$\frac{r}{h} = \frac{4~\text{ft}}{10~\text{ft}} = \frac{2}{5}$$ where $r$ is the radius of the oil when its depth is $h$.  Also, note that the volume of a cone is $$V = \frac{1}{3}\pi r^2h$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this kind of problem, I would suggest drawing the conical shaped tank in a cartesian coordinate system with the origin at the point where the oil is being pumped at the top of the tank. The trick is to point the $x$-axis downwards, parallel to the height of the tank, and point the $y$-axis sideways, parallel to the radius of the tank.

Then, find an equation for the radius of the conical shaped tank with respect to $x$. If you look at the cartesian coordinate system, the shape looks like a slope intercepting the $y$-axis at the origin and passing by the point $(10,4)$. So the equation is

$$
(y - 4) = \frac{4}{10}(x - 10) \\
y = \frac{2x}{5} \\
$$

An element of volume is then a circular disk having thickness $\Delta_i x$ and radius $f(x_i)$, where $f(x) = y$. The volume of this element is

$$
\Delta_i V = \pi [f(x_i)]^2 \Delta_i x
$$

Given the motor oil weighs $32 \, lbs/ft^3$, then $32 \Delta_i V$ is the force required to pump an element and $32 \Delta_i V x_i$ is the work needed to pump it to the top of the tank. Thus

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
W &=& \lim_{||\Delta|| \to 0} \sum_{i=1}^n 32 \pi [f(x_i)]^2 x_i \Delta_i x \\
&=& 32 \pi \int_{7.5}^{10} \! [\frac{2x}{5}]^2 x \, \textrm{d}x \\
&=& \frac{128}{25} \pi \int_{7.5}^{10} \! x^3 \, \textrm{d}x \\
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Comment: Why is it $\int_{7.5}^{10}$ and not $\int_{2.5}^{10}$?

Comment: If you draw the conical shaped tank with the apex at the origin and point the $x$-axis downwards towards the base of the tank, then you will encounter the initial surface of the oil at $x = 7.5$ and the bottom at $x = 10$. In other words, you will have to pump the oil at the initial surface a distance of $7.5$ feet and pump the oil at the bottom of the tank a distance of $10$ feet. To verify this makes sense, you will have to pump a total of $2.5$ feet of oil which is what you have in your tank.

Comment: Oh, okay. Does it change anything if the liquid is being pumped out of the apex? (i.e. the base is on the x-axis, and the point is at $(0,10)$. There was a picture with the problem that showed it that way, didn't realize until you put that comment that that's not very well stated in the words. (Sorry about that).

Comment: Yes, I understood the problem as the oil being pumped out of the apex which is pointing upwards. For this problem, as well as other similar work-related problems, it's important to place the origin at the point where the liquid is being pumped. The reason is that you want to express the distance that the liquid has to travel as the interval of your integral. For example, if you know intuitively that the liquid will have to travel $7.5$ feet at the beginning and $10$ feet at the end, then your picture better reflect those numbers so that you can define your integral accordingly.

Comment: Gotcha. Thank you very much!